# Django - Filter objects based on their ForeignKey but with multiple choices?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-filter

I am developing an app where each `User` is associated with a list of languages he or she speaks. The app is about books and each `Book` has a language field representing the language the book is written in.

**I am trying to fetch all books written in the user's language*s*. So if a user speaks English *AND* Spanish I want to retrieve all books written in English *AND* Spanish.**

My code:

**users/models.py**:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language)
```

**books/models.py**:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
```

**books/views.py**: This code does not actually work but I posted it to hopefully convey what I am trying to achieve:

```
class BooksView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        books = Book.objects.filter(language=request.user.languages)
        return books
```

**Instead of `Book.objects.filter(language=request.user.languages)`, how can I filter books based on not *ONE* language but *MULTIPLE* languages?**

Comment: I have updated the question. You can see how I am actually getting the token now. However, you are right. If I hard-code the token it all works. Do you know why can't I access cookies from getStaticProps()?

Comment: The cookie is not HTTP only as of now (although I might change it in the future). Do you know how could I pass the cookies to getStaticProps()? Maybe using getInitialProps()?

Comment: Deleting my comments as you've edited this question to something else entirely. Please do not that in the future for the benefit of community and future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter using multiple values you should use `__in` filter - it will look for particular query in an iterable so in you case it would look like this

```
class BooksView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        books = Book.objects.filter(language__in=request.user.languages.all())
        return books
```

BTW logically speaking the statement "books written English AND Spanish" would imply that particular book has to be written in two versions I think you ment "books written English OR Spanish" but if that's not what you ment im sorry for that assumtion

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I meant all books written in English AND all books written in Spanish.